# I'm looking for a Gem that assists in monitoring and reporting on various tasks that run in my rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I have a rails application that will be running various tasks and scripts throughout the day. I'm planning on using Active Admin as my administration framework, but I'd like to find a Gem that I could integrate into my application that will provide status monitoring on all the tasks and scripts that will be running in the application.

Is anyone aware of or have experience with such a gem or alternatively has anyone rolled this functionality themselves and would be willing to share your approach.

Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [God gem](http://godrb.com/) has been around for a long time, but it's [actively maintained](http://rubygems.org/gems/god/versions) and should provide a lot of functionality you seek. It also enables easily configurable email notifications.

EDIT:

Although I personally use God (if for no reason than it's the first process manager I've worked with), I'd be remiss not to mention two other gems that are seemingly on the rise:

1. [Foreman](https://github.com/ddollar/foreman) – Manages Procfile-based applications ([Railscast #281](http://railscasts.com/episodes/281-foreman))
2. [Monit Rubygem](https://github.com/matiaskorhonen/monit) – A Ruby interface for [Monit](http://mmonit.com/) ([Railscast #475 (Pro)](http://railscasts.com/episodes/375-monit))

I should also add that none of the above three gems are Rails specific, but can (presumably) be applied to a wide variety of Ruby applications.